# Why do I see an alternate image/viedo when I change the image link slightly?

Tags: support, images, image-upload

The title accompanied by [this](https://i.gyazo.com/cc3206dfe6017ee9b3d495ce33f45d62.mp4) should be rather self explanatory. I removed the `.` in the URL `i.stack[...]` to `istack[...]` and it changes the image completely. The [URL](https://istack.imgur.com/) doesn't seem to exist so I'm not too sure what it might be.

Why does it change to something completely different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're changing the imgur subdomain in that link.

I'm pretty sure imgur just discards invalid subdomains, and there happens to be an image with the same ID on imgur.com:

Link: `https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mmqg.jpg`
Image: 
[image]

Comment: Ah, makes sense. Their fallback approach threw me off quite a bit.